# Clustering Algorithm - Applied to a set of Earthquake Data

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

So I'm looking to apply a clustering algorithm to the earth data provided by the usgs.

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/

My main goal is to determine the top 10 most dangerous places (either by amount of earthquakes or the magnitude of an earthquake that a place experiences) to be based on an earthquake feed.

Are there any suggestions on how to do it? I'm looking at k-means then just taking the sum of the k-means (with each earthquake magnitude weighted in each cluster) to look at the most dangerous clusters.

I'm also writing this in ruby as a code reference.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain "dangerous places" or formulate it? You mean the sum of all earthquake's magnitude in a cluster ?

Comment: if you define the dangerousness value of a cluster as sum of all earthquakes' magnitude in the cluster, then you don't need to use magnitude to find clusters. BTW, I think density based clustering algorithms are more suitable for this type of questions that may include arbitrary shape clusters.

Comment: Hey I updated the question, that makes sense to basically do a standard cluster algorithm, then just add up the sums to compare the magnitude. Any other perspectives will always be cool though.

Answer (score 2):

K-means can't handle outliers in the data set very well.

Furthermore, it is designed around *variance*, but variance in latitude and longitude is not really meaningful. In fact, k-means cannot handle the latitude +-180° wrap-around. Instead, you will want to use the **great-circle distance**.

So try to use a *density* based clustering algorithm that allows you to use distances such as the great-circle distance!

Read up on Wikipedia and a good book on cluster analysis.